# how can I make a grid?

Tags: numerics, list-manipulation

I would like to make a grid for x between 0 to 1
and use following Table

```
N = 150 (*N number of data between 0 to 1*)
xs = Table[Exp[Log[10^(-4)]*(N - i + 1)/N], {i, 1, N}] // N;
```

but as you can see distribution of points in low x is more than large x. But I need a code which produces more point in large x (and less points in low x).

Comment: Don't you get some information like "Set::wrsym: Symbol N is Protected."?!

Comment: Do not use Capital letters for your symbols, you'll get mixed up with reserved symbols (like `N`).

Comment: Sorry, but without a bit more information about what you are trying to achieve I cannot help you.

Comment: I guess you use misleading words. Have a look at Menu/Help/WolframDocumentation/Grid. Do you use the word "grid" in the same sense? If not, explain please what are you after?

Answer (score 4):

One way to get a denser set of points near 1 than near 0 is to move the origin:

```
n = 150;
xs = Reverse[1 - Table[Exp[Log[10.^(-4)]*(n - i + 1)/n], {i, 1, n}]]
```

Comment: Dear @bill s, thank you very much indeed. that was very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

You could raise your weights to a power greater than `1`.  E.g.,

```
n = 150 (* number of data between 0 to 1*)
xs = Table[Exp[Log[10^(-4)]*Power[(n - i + 1)/n, 5]], {i, 1, n}] // N;
```

But probably you just want move the subdivision location:

```
xs = Table[Exp[Log[10^(-4)*(n - i + 1)/n]], {i, 1, n}] // N;
```